# Are you able to create a dashboard that summarizes lists across multiple SharePoint Sites?

Tags: dashboard

Our team uses multiple SharePoint sites for various projects. Each one has multiples lists for tasks and projects that members of our team is on. We are hoping to create a SharePoint Dashboard across the multiples sites.